# Magento 2 : Add tooltip to shipping methods

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

Can I add a tooltip to each shipping method in Magento 2? If so, how? 
I need to display additional information to each shipping method say place of origin. I cannot seem to add a column to the shipping methods. I do not need to save this information to the database.

Is there a way to display some information when we shipping method is chosen?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you got any solution for this issue?

Comment: No solution yet

Comment: Hi Have you got solution for this ?

Comment: No solution. Just added the additional information in parentheses with the method title

Answer (score 0):

I have found a sort of work around for this. It requires you to have your own child theme with css fule

From the Magento Checkout module make a copy of
view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-item.html

Place this code in your child theme at
Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-address-shipping-method-item.html

In this new file create a new row and column or div. I used a div like this:

```
    <div class="col-description"
         attr="'id': 'description_' + method.method_code"></div>
```

Run **bin/magento setup:upgrade**

Now use your browser console to see what the id is for each shipping method. One of mine was 'description_bestway'

[image]

Now in the _theme.less or _extend.less of your child theme add something like this

```
#description_bestway:before {
  content: "This is the description for Table Rate shipping";
}
```

Run **bin/magento setup:upgrade**